# Node.js : How to run a special function as server starts as a initialization?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I use Express framework, I have this function and I want to run it in intervals since server starts:

```
setTimeout(function () {
    console.log('timeout completed');
}, 1000);
```

so i put this piece of code to the initial file of Express.js Framework called App.js but it only runs twice, where is the problem and how could I fix it?

Comment: Use `setInterval`. See https://nodejs.org/api/timers.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `setTimeout` function runs **only once** when that amount of time is completed,
here in your case it is 1s(1000ms).

Instead you may want to use `setInterval` which does the same thing except that it doesn't stop until you tell it so.

Here is an example :

```
var max = 3;
var i = 0;

var timer = setInterval(function(){
   if(i === max){
      // stop the timer from looping.
      clearInterval(timer);
   }else{
      i++;
   }   
},1000);
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are describing a cron sort of job, why don't you use any of the many node crons modules instead.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cron

Check that out, pretty straight forward.